# Update text block from downloaded text file = RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am learning Windows Phone 8.1 development, I have probably done something utterly incorrectly programming wise

The need: I want to download a text file from the web using `HttpClient()` and display it in the `TextBlock1`

From variety of tutorials I have found the following:

```
    public async void DownloadDataAsync()
    {
        string data = "some link to Textfile.txt";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(data);
        HttpContent content = response.Content;
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        UpdateTextBlock1(result);
    }
```

Then the other functions.

```
    public void UpdateTextBlock1(string result)
    {

        TextBlock1.Text = result;
    }

    private void BtnDownloadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Task t = new Task(DownloadDataAsync);
        t.Start();

    }
```

The code starts well enough - on button pressed, I receive RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD.

Is it that I'm trying to call the method when all threads haven't finished? How can I code that efficently so the TextBlock1 is updated with txt data?

Thanks for understanding, baby steps here in programming, and I couldn't find a relevant answer over google. (Maybe I don't yet know how to ask?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the textblock on the UI thread like so:

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
{
  TextBlock1.Text = result;
});
```

There are many posts on this subject.

Comment: No problem. Don't worry, ever developer has run into this problem many times. UI thread is for getting input and updating controls, try to do everything else on other threads.